# .NET ASMX web service to use WSDL file on disk instead of auto gen?

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I've got a WSDL file created in Altova XMLSpy, that is then used in Altova Mapforce to map out a service.  This is then used to create a .NET service (asmx).

The problem is the way Altova Mapforce generates the service webmethod.  Instead of the interface created in the WSDL you get a generic webmethod that takes a parameter of type array.  The mapping code in the service is based on the WSDL definition so the code knows how to do the heavy lifting based on the contents of the array.

The issue is that when you query the service like localhost/service_name.asmx?WSDL you only get a WSDL for the generic webmethod, not the interface defined in the WSDL file.

I think this configuration of WSDL file and generic webmethod/array work in Apache as I believe it will serve up a separate WSDL file instead of generating the WSDL on the fly like .NET does.

So, is there a way to serve up the WSDL file instead of the generated WSDL that .NET normally returns?  Am I stuck just providing a catalog of WSDL files to consumers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're stuck using legacy code (ASMX), then you're stuck serving up individual WSDL files.

WCF fixes this.

Comment: Just to be clear, you  are saying that it is possible to get WCF to return a WSDL file from disk when using ?WSDL, but I'm just going to have to give out a URL to a catalog of WSDL's for ASMX's instead of allowing autogen?